# How to show the full image instead of a cropped version?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building a website using HTML/CSS/Bootstrap/Js. 
Now I am at a part where I want to overlay a jumbotron on a container with a background image using z-index.

But for some reason the image which I am using as the background-image keeps getting cropped to only show the upper part .

I have tried changing the height attributes but the issue is that i want it to be responsive.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid  mt-5" >
      <div class="row imagez" >
        <div class="col-12 px-0 mt-5 mb-5">



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.imagez {
 background-image:  url("../flying.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;

 }
```

I expect to have a container where the entire image is always shown in full no matter what the resolution is of the browser

Comment: Try using background-size: contain;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background-size: contain;
```

This will resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible, while `background-size: cover;` resizes the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges.

Comment: Now it does show the full image but only in the left corner. My final goal is to have it always  being a container-filling image. I can share a working example from a website i use as reference if that helps